# Creating list of lists in c++

Tags: python, c++, list, vector

In C++, what is the recommended way of creating a list of a certain size, where each element of the list is a list of 3 elements?

#### Analogy

To clarify, the analogy in Python for what I'm trying to do would go as follows:

Simplest:

```
n = 10
ls = [[0,0,0] for i in range(n)]
```

Already initialised as well *and* I can access elements (e.g. `ls[0][0]`) and even modify them (`ls[0][0]=2`), perfect!

or using numpy

```
import numpy as np
n  = 10 #number of elements
ls = np.empty((n,0)).tolist()
```

and then to each element (here a list), we'd append our 3 values.

#### Basic attempt

Now I understand in C++, one starting difference would be to specifically define the type of variables the inner-lists are supposed to contain. But `vector` is not a variable type in c++ right? As in something along the lines of:

```
int n = 4;
vector<vector> ls(4);
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    ls[i] = {0,0,0};
}
```

would be wrong. Moreover, if I try instead `vector<int> ls;` then I cannot assign lists to each element.

**Question:**

- Is there a way to make htis work using `vector` in C++?
- Alternatively, are there simpler ways of going about this?

Comment: You shouldn't tag Python since your problem has nothing to do with Python, even if you are using it as an example.

Comment: `std::vector` is a container, but it's certainly not a list.

Comment: I'd use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` for something like this.

Comment: If the inner element's size is a compile-time constant, `std::vector<std::array<int, 3>>` may be preferable.

Comment: @François Andrieux good point.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks a lot Francois, you mean if the inner-elements are not going to change size?

Comment: @user929304 If you know at compile time the size you need, you could use `std::array` instead of `std::vector`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Alright, in order to be able to easily access the elements, is it okay if I used `int ls [n][3];` instead of `std::array`?

Comment: @user929304 `int [n][3]` is not the same as `std::array<int, 3>`. Rather, `int [3]` would be very similar to `std::array<int, 3>`. But there is very rarely a good reason to use a c array like `int [3]` over `std::array<int, 3>`. You mention ease of access, but both `std::vector` and `std::array` support `operator[]`. They are all equally ease to access,

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Indeed, thanks. I do know the size of the inner-lists at compile-time, but the size of the main list itself is only known in run-time. Hence I've used `vector<array<int,3>> ls;` and in the run-time the size of the outer vector is determined by `ls.resize(n);` With `n=4` as example. But when I print the values, `cout << ls[0][0] << endl;` it's fine, but even if I continue the 2nd index (which should go upto 2-included only as the inner-array are of size 3) it still returns values instead of giving error, for instance `cout << ls[0][4] << endl;` print `0`!! This is strange

Comment: @user929304 Accessing an element beyond the bounds of an array (or vector) is undefined behavior. Errors in c++ are not always required to produce a diagnostic (a visible error or crash) but the resulting behavior is undefined, it can do *anything*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest to the Python code that I can think of is:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> ls(10, std::vector<int>(3));
```

If the sizes are known at compile time, you may also use `std::array`.

```
std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 10> ls;
```

Comment: @user929304, the code as posted in my answer will zero initialize the elements of `ls`. You don't need to write code to initialize the elements of the array to 0. `cout << ls[0]` is not natively supported by the language or the standard library. You'll have to write a function in your application to be able to do that.

Comment: @user929304, that's correct but it's better. You get all the goodies of the built in array and a few more with `std::array`.

Comment: Since I only know the inner-list sizes at compile-time, I've done the following: `vector<array<int,3>> ls;` and `ls.resize(n);` to define the size of the outer-vector in run-time, (with `n` being set to 4). But strangely when I try to print `ls[0][4]` it doesn't give error but prints 0, I mean the second index of ls should only go from 0 to 2, because the inner-lists are arrays of size 3. What's going on? :)

Comment: @user929304, It works because both `std::vector` and `std::array` use contiguous data. In theory, it's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a 2d vector with each vector having a size of 3 like this:

```
std::vector<vector<int>> someVec;
someVec.resize( n , std::vector<int>(3));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

> In c++, what is the recommended way of creating a list of a certain
>   size, where each element of the list is a list of 3 elements?
>
> [...]
>
> Already initialised

If 3 is fixed at compile time, then you can use `std::array<T, 3>` as the outer container's element type. And if the "certain size" is not certain until runtime, then the outer container will be something dynamic, like `std::list`.

Let's suppose `T` is `int` like in your examples:

```
#include <list>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::list<std::array<int, 3>> list(n, { 1, 2, 3 });
    for (auto const& array : list)
    {
        std::cout << array[0] << ", " << array[1] << ", " << array[2] << '\n';
    }
}
```

Note how I used the [second `std::list` constructor overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/list) to specify the value (`std::array<int, 3> { 1, 2, 3 }`) with which to initialise every element.

If you don't actually need a *list* with its particular iterator semantics, then prefer `std::vector` over `std::list`.

Comment: Very good complement to the other answers, thanks a lot.